# Why does this very basic redirect module not work 100% of the time? Caching or something?

Tags: 7, redirection

```
global $user;
  // Check if logged in
  if ($user->uid)  {
        if (arg(0) == null && !in_array('administrator', array_values($user->roles)) && !in_array('h5p', array_values($user->roles))){
    //redirect user to group page if they are loggged in
    $user = user_load($user->uid);
    $argument = $user->field_group_id_for_rules['und'][0]['value'];
      drupal_goto('node/' . $argument);
    }
}
```

I just want users to get redirected to the NID saved in their profiles.. It works 98% of the time but really ruins the user experience when it doesn't.

Also, is it a bad approach or inefficient?

Edit: The fixed code with `drupal_is_front_page()` which didn't work before without `hook_init()`.

```
<?php 
function custom_hp_redirect_init() {
global $user;
  if ($user->uid)  {
        if (drupal_is_front_page() && !in_array('administrator', array_values($user->roles)) && !in_array('h5p', array_values($user->roles))){
    //redirect user to activity page if they are loggged in
    $user = user_load($user->uid);
    $argument = $user->field_group_id_for_rules['und'][0]['value'];
      drupal_goto('node/' . $argument);
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: It could be many reasons, it depends on what is the condition you set before implementing the redirection or which hook function you write into. Maybe you add a `watchdog()` before `drupal_goto()`.

Comment: That's literally the entire module minus the opening php tag.. I'm doing it wrong, yea?

Comment: I never read `$user` object without and function wrapped. At least I will implement `hook_init()` if you want to run it in the very beginning of page load.

Comment: `I just want users to get redirected to the NID saved in their profiles` but when? when they save a node? when they log in? be more specific

Comment: On the homepage. I chose arg(0) == null because drupal_is_front_page() wouldn't work for me. But it should be fixed now because putting drupal_is_front_page() inside hook_init() function makes it work. I'm hoping my 98% will rise to 100% redirects. Question has been edited.

Comment: `hook_init` doesn't run for cached pages. So yeah, caching